# Fullscreen background video and keep it centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, video

I'm trying to create a site where I have a background video playing with some HTML5.
This is all working perfectly, it works just the way I want it.
But I also want to keep the image centered on the screen, even when a user resizes the browser.

```
<video id="video" src="video/video.mov" type="video/mov" autoplay loop></video>
```

I got this to work with some jQuery, but was wondering if there is a CSS solution for this.

```
function resizeHandler() {
        // scale the video
        var documentHeight = $(document).height();
        var documentWidth = $(document).width();
        var ratio = $('#video').width() / $('#video').height();

        if((documentWidth / documentHeight) < ratio) {
            $('#video').css({
                'width': 'auto',
                'height': '100%',
                'left': '0px',
                'right': '0px',
                'top': '0px',
                'bottom': '0px'
            })

            var marginRight = $('#video').width() - $(document).width();
            $('#video').css('left', -marginRight);
        } else {
            $('#video').css({
                'width': '100%',
                'height': 'auto',
                'left': '0px',
                'right': '0px',
                'top': '0px',
                'bottom': '0px'
            })

            var marginTop = $('#video').height() - $(document).height();
            $('#video').css('top', -marginTop);
        }
    }
```

This is the jQuery I wrote to stretch the image to fit the screen, and to keep the image sort of centered.
Not sure if this is possible in CSS, but if somebody knows how to, this might be nice.

Comment: is there a functional reason why you care about achieving this in css? if it works, it works.

Comment: Not really, I'm just curious whether it's possible or not in CSS, just curiosity.

Comment: Does this center your video at any browser size?

Comment: The best way to achieve this with CSS is with the object-fit property.  It works in all browsers for video, except for IE and Edge.  You can upvote it on the Microsoft Developer forum here:
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/32011258-object-fit-and-object-position-for-all-media-elem?category_id=86947  You can use a JS polyfill in the meantime, but if it gets more votes it will be implemented

Answer (score 7):

This question just have been referenced into [Place video with 100% height & 100% width using css or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574285/place-video-with-100-height-100-width-using-css-or-javascript/28574544)

I guess my answer for that could be the one you were looking for?

Here's the code:

```css
header {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 0;
}
header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font: 3em/1.4 helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff
}
header video {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Sample Title</h1>
 <video autoplay loop class="bg-video">
  <source src="https://d2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net/video/preview/abstract-rainbow_wjpctkdes__PM.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
</header>
```

And here's a [working fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2jyLnm3L/).

Hope it'll help someone else :)

Answer (score 4):

I would try centering the video with position absolute inside of a fixed wrapper. So for example:

**Place your video inside of a fixed wrapper with 100% width and height:**

```
#video-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Center the video inside of an extra large area with margin auto:**

```
#video {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    bottom: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    right: -9999px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

**And stretch it to full size with min-width and min-height:**

```
#video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

---

**Here the final result:**

```css
#video-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#video {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    bottom: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    right: -9999px;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;   
}
```

```html
<div id="video-wrap">
    <video id="video" loop autoplay>
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</div>
```

Here also a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcuvbgv8/4/)**.

Answer (score 1):

This should make `#video` the entire size of the viewport and remain there when the user scrolls.

```
#video {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how will it make the video fit the browser window and scale it proportionally?
I used the same css code already, but I wasn't able to recreate my jQuery with CSS

Answer (score 0):

Use Css Property. object-fit: cover;

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<video controls> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp type=video/3gp>
</video>
```