# Keep the center of a video element always in the center of the browser?

Tags: html, css

I have a video element. When the page is resized I want it to clip in from all sides and keep a certain point of the video always centred, how would I do this?

EDIT:

All the code I have so far

```
<body>
<video>
    <source src="img/background.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
    <source src="img/background.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
</video>
</body>
```

CSS

```
video{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090595/center-fullscreen-background-video/18091239#18091239

Comment: Alternatively wrap it in a `<div>` with `overflow` set to `hidden` and use relative positioning

Comment: Can it be done with pure HTML/CSS?

Comment: Best to provide actual code for people to play with

Comment: @gvee Added the little bit I have there

Comment: Can you create a working JSFiddle please? (http://jsfiddle.net/) I, for one, don't have a file here to test the video element with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `position:fixed` and setting the `top:50%`, `left:50%`.

Comment: ...that will position the top-left part of the element in the middle of the screen, not the element itself. You will have to use negative margins equal to half the width and height of the element to centre it properly..