# Show a video-tag maximized and centered in a div

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I want to show a video by video html5 tag in a fixed div. I maximize it by using min-height and max-height. But I also want it to be centered.

```
<div class="fixed-width-height">
    <video style="min-width:100%; min-height:100%;" controls autoplay>
        <source src="myvid.mpg" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag
    </video>
</div>
```

Right now, the div always shows the upper / or left part of the video depending on the size of the div. It would be best it always shows the center.

**UPDATE**:
The video tag is now centered, great work of **jbutler483** but there is a problem with the video size depending on the framing div or the video ratio or size. The video doesn't cover the whole area or the centering fails. Here is a snipped that does fit the needs on a 400x400 box but fails at 1000x200. http://jsfiddle.net/cremers/7Lgfyg1d/6/

**UPDATE**:
Found a working solutions for non-IE: `object-fit: cover; object-position:center;` But I'd like to have a full working solution.

**UPDATE**:
[Polyfill](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit#readme) should provide the desired function, I will test this on video tags this days, thx to **Philip Dernovoy**.
*UPDATE*: I am sorry but I didn't get that working.

Comment: can you create a demo?

Comment: Demos in action below.

Comment: I reworked my answer. Fiddle working now...

Comment: Sorry, the first one is not centered and doesn't have the propper height (its bigger than maximum height). The second one is not centered also, and wider than 100%.

Comment: Is javascript allowed ?

Comment: I'm working with pure javascript atm.

Comment: To UPDATE2: there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit#readme) fo `object-fit`

Comment: @PhilipDernovoy Looks good, is aimed at image tags but may work for video tags, I'll have a look.

Comment: @vickisys Not suitable, but thank you.

Comment: I search and i found a stake overflow link Check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090595/center-fullscreen-background-video

Comment: @AhmadSaad It's jQuery but a good & simple solution to compare div & video tag ratio and either set height or width attribute to 100%. I'll have a hand on this.

Answer (score 9):

You could use a combination of positioning and translations to achieve this:

```css
.fixed-width-height {
  position: relative;
}
.fixed-width-height video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-width-height">
  <video style="min-width:100%; min-height:100%;" controls autoplay>
    <source src="myvid.mpg" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag
  </video>
</div>
```

---

**Note:**

This will/should work with all browsers bar IE8>= nor Opera Mini as shown [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=translate) In these browsers, the video will be displayed in the top left corner of the fixed-width-height element (although will still be functional).

---

If you wanted to 'cover' the whole div, you could use:

```
.fixed-width-height video{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

in order to completely cover + stretch to the relatively positioned div parent.

Comment: Okay I have one problem with that solution: If the video is 800 width and the div is smaller, lets say 400, the video is bigger that the width and will not be shrunk to 400px width. I'm aware it is the problem of my min- css, ist there any workaround?

Comment: @Daniel: I can't test but set a `max-width` to `100%` on the video.

Comment: @PavelGatnar: That is correct, although I wanted to show OP how this was achieved by splitting the two.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cremers/7Lgfyg1d/4/ cannot get that fiddle to work, it looks worse that my local project here. Setting a 100% max-width will result in height not to be variable.

Comment: @Daniel: I hope you 'love me' enough not to use inline styling, and instead use classes: [Could you possibly explain the issue here?](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/7Lgfyg1d/5/) - do you want the height to be full height as well?

Comment: @jbutler483 I'm sorry, yes thats it. I want it to cover the div and its size being as minimal as possible. So it should be okay and centered in a 400x400 box and also in a 1000x200 box.

Comment: @PavelGatnar try it yourself, setting the width or height alone won't fix the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/cremers/7Lgfyg1d/6/  If I change the css, one of the samples is not correct.

Comment: @jbutler483 the video should cover the divs.

Comment: @PavelGatnar Please press "run" and see the result.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if I understood what you want. For the video tag, I used to use object-contain and object-position to handle most layout requirements.
With the jsfiddle you gave, try change the 'child' class to :

```
.child{
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    object-fit:contain;
    object-position:center;
}
```

This will make the video fill to full width or full height depending on the h/w ratio. If you want the video to fill all the div with some part of it overflowed, simply change object-fit to cover.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, as stated in the update 7th may, object-fit works only in non IE. But your object-position was unknown jet, thanks!

Comment: May be thats only for chrome, but brilliant solution anyways!

Answer (score 0):

add this style to video:

```
position: absolute;
min-height: 50%;
min-width: 50%; 
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
```

and this style to the div container: `position:relative;`

http://jsfiddle.net/4k0bpek4/2/

Comment: Sorry, no effect on video tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think a 'flex' property is the best for this situation. Here is the code:

```js
document.querySelector('body').onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('body').style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
  window.onresize = function () {
    document.querySelector('body').style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.fixed-width-height {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}

video {
  width: 100%; height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-width-height">
  <video controls autoplay>
    <source src="myvid.mpg" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag
  </video>
</div>
```

Is that what are you talking about? (It may not completely pure HTML/CSS, but I think it working anyway.)

Comment: Sorry, your solution doesnt fill the whole div.

Comment: @Daniel I think the ratio is up to the file. Have you tried with the file has other ratio yet?

Comment: I want to play different videos ratio and sizes in different div sizes. The video should fit in a div so it fills the div completely, keeps its ratio and the therefore produced overflow should be hidden. The showed part of the video should be vertically and horizontally centered.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for..

```
    .fixed-width-height {
        margin: 3px 0px 8px 10px;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .child {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px #ef7f1b solid;
        padding: 6px;
    }

<div class="fixed-width-height">
<video class="child" controls="" autoplay="">
    <source src="http://beginwithsoftware.com/free-hd-720p-1080p-mp4-video-downloads/video/I_LOVE_YOU_H264_720P_23.976_BeginWithSoftware.com.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4cbnj0tc/

Comment: the surrounding div doesn't have a fixed height or width. If you change it, you can see that the height will not be filled and it won't center.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<div class="fixed-width-height">
  <video style="min-width:100%; min-height:100%;" controls autoplay>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Browser Not Supported
  </video>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.fixed-width-height {
  position: relative;
}
.fixed-width-height video {  
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    object-fit:contain;
    object-position:center;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

think this one will help you..:D

```css
#myplayer {
 position:fixed;
 top:25%;
 left:25%;
 bottom:25%;
 right:25%;
 display:block;
 background:#000;
}
#defaultplayer {
 position:absolute;
 height:99%;
 width:99%;
 background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div id="myplayer"><video id="defaultplayer" src="your url" controls></video></div>
```

Comment: Sry, the video will not fit into a varying div. But good work on that one, Maybe someone will need this kind of positioning.

Comment: i have edited the code.. mayb this time it will help you