# Place video with 100% height & 100% width using css or javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to place a html5 video (with the video tag of course) with 100% width and 100% height which will play in the background. Here is an example with an image and I want exactly the same with a video, I just didn't find out how to do that:

```
#image {
    background-image: url("image.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u9ncpyfu/**

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911225/fullscreen-background-video-and-keep-it-centered

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may try:

```css
header {
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 0;
}
header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font: 3em/1.4 helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff
}
header video {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Sample Title</h1>
 <video autoplay loop class="bg-video">
  <source src="https://d2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net/video/preview/abstract-rainbow_wjpctkdes__PM.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
</header>
```

It will **keep the aspect ratio and the video centered while always fully covering the container**.

Here's a [fiddle working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/2jyLnm3L/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is pretty cool, but why wrap it in the `header` element?

Comment: As stated in the question, the video is supposed to be the background of something... I used a `header` but it could be, for example, a `div` or even, if properly CSS styled, the `body` :)

Comment: Fair-enough. [Here's a variation on this for a fixed background](http://jsfiddle.net/dnwk4t88/).

Comment: And here's [another version for a fixed background without container](http://jsfiddle.net/2jyLnm3L/1/).

Comment: That's what I've always searched for! The JSFiddle without container is great :)

Comment: Great, finally a working CSS solution and no JS required.  Excellent!

Comment: Perfect. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, this should be as simple as setting the min-height and min-width to 100%. So for example:

```
#video {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

This may need to be adjusted for responsiveness.

Check out this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9ncpyfu/4/)**.

---

**Edit:**

If you also want the video to remain centered, then wrap it in a container like so:

```css
#video-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#video {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    bottom: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    right: -9999px;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;   
}
```

```html
<div id="video-wrap"><video id="video">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</div>
```

Here also a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcuvbgv8/)**.

Comment: This works, but that's not really what I wanted: Your example moves the video to the right when you resize your browser, I want that you can always see 100% of the video

Comment: Actually, in the edit I provided the video should remain centered and at 100% as long as there is room for it. No different than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Set

```
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
```

You can forget about `height: 100%`, it only stretches to contain 100% of a div's interior content.

Comment: [That won't work, because it will constrain proportions](http://jsfiddle.net/gcfuyeej/). The video will letterbox. Also, [not having width/height properties does not work](http://jsfiddle.net/97ao0raf/).

Comment: It didn't suggest disregarding the width property--just the height property. You can't consistently stretch a video fullwidth with any serious css-support in most browsers. If you want to center the video set `margin: auto`;

Answer (score 0):

Easy if you give the HTML and BODY a height of 100%.

[WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Godisgood/u9ncpyfu/5/)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<video controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If you look at your example, you can see that left & right is white

Comment: Also, giving body a height of 100% will result in scrolling events not working anymore.